# Force div to display on page load - jQuery / CSS

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm building a single page menu that shows/hides div 'frames' rather than loading new pages. The (almost) working setup can be found build on **[This Pen](http://codepen.io/ajm90UK/pen/VmBwxR)**. The problem I have is showing the first page/frame by default, and after that have it behave as the rest do in switching between display block/none.

**Using CSS/jQuery (whichever is cleaner) how can I show the first frame by default?** This seems frustratingly straightforward but I can't get my head round it. For reference my jQuery and CSS are below:

```
#item-1, #item-2, #item-3, #item-4, #item-5 {
  display: none;
}
#item-1:target, #item-2:target, #item-3:target, #item-4:target, #item-5:target {
  display:block;
}

//show first frame on page load
$('window').onload(function() {
   $('#item-1').show();
})
```

Please refer to the Pen for all code and let me know if I can expand on anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not `.show()` but rather update the window hash on document ready for this to display correctly.

However, adjust your codepen accordingly to just contain this block:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  //show first frame on page load
  $('#item-1').show();
})
```

see:

    `$(document).ready(function() {
      window.location.hash = '#item-1';
    })`

Comment: Thanks, same as below - I tried this but it keeps it's 'show()' status despite clicking to other frames

Comment: This does seem to have worked :) I would never of thought of using hash - I'll need to look into that

Comment: It's because you're using :target to display the block and this is controlled via the hash.

Comment: Great, I can't help thinking there's a simpler way to achieve what I want across HTML CSS and jQuery but that's another problem I suppose

Answer (score 1):

**[Updated codePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RoBNeK)**.

Using jQuery the solution could be :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a[href="#item-1"]')[0].click();
})
```

Clicking the link of the first `frame`.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

`onload` is a javascript event, not a jquery method.

So, in jquery, you can try :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#item-1').show();
});
```

Suppose, you want to do this in javascript, you can use :

```
window.onload = $('#item-1').show();
```

or

```
window.onload = document.getElementById('item-1').display = 'block';
```

Comment: Thanks, I had this, but it never loses it's 'show' status when clicking the other items